# How to update ListBox when ObservableCollection items changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have test app which adding items to ListBox in loop. Now, ListBox updates, when all items added to ObservableCollection. I need to update ListBox when every item added. Please, help russian guy =)

Here is my code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,288.04,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="urlsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Urls}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="417"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.GetUrls();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Url> Urls { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Urls = new ObservableCollection<Url>();
    }

    public void GetUrls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Urls.Add(new Url { link = i.ToString() });
            //Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }
}

public class Url
{
    public string link { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I click the button and 5 items are added to to `ListBox`, is that not happening for you?

Comment: Have you looked in to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your collection?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to notify the UI about the change happening in the URL observable collection each time it adds a new item.

If you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your view model then register the observable collection with any change happening in it.

```
private ObservableCollection<Url> _urls; 
public ObservableCollection<Url> Urls 
{ get
  { 
    return _urls;
  } 
  set
  {
    _urls = value;
    OnPropertyModified("Urls");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `UI to update on every item addition` in collection i guess.

Looking at `Thread.Sleep(300)`, i am assuming you want to wait for 300 milliseconds before adding another item to collection.

`DispatcherTimer` is what you are looking for then. This sample will work:

```
public void GetUrls()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
    int i = 0;
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
       {
           Urls.Add(new Url { link = i.ToString() });
           ++i;
           if (i == 5)
             timer.Stop();
       };
    timer.Start();
}
```

This will add item in collection after every 300 ms and will stop timer once item count reaches to 5.

---

Like i mentioned in comment

> Dispatcher associated with UI thread can process one operation at a
>   time. When it's adding item to collection, it can't process Rendering
>   operation at same time. Hence GUI not getting refreshed. Usage of DispatcherTimer gives some time to rendering operations to get processed.

Another approach without `DispatcherTimer` would be to `enqueue empty delegate on UI dispatcher with Render priority` so that all operations with priority higher than Render (including Render) gets processed before moving to addition of another item in collection.

```
public void GetUrls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Urls.Add(new Url { link = i.ToString() });
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }),
                                               DispatcherPriority.Render);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is works, but not what i actually need. I used Thread.Sleep(300) to emulate longworking operation. I don't now how many time it will get. 
I think i need to use Task, but my attempts were unsuccessful =(

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. You said you want to update UI on every addition (exactly what i provided in my answer). You have to explain more that what exactly you are looking for. You need to define `what actually you need`.

Comment: I need to update UI on every addition. But in your example you used timer to update collection. I wouldn't like to use timer, because I do not need it. Is any another way to update UI without timer?

Comment: Dispatcher associated with UI thread can process one operation at a time. When it's adding item to collection, it can't process Rendering operation at same time. Hence GUI not getting refreshed. That's why i used DispatcherTimer so that rendering operation gets time to process. You can set timespan to some lower value say 50 ms in case time is too long between addition.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! But i will continue my research about this question.

Comment: Added with another approach what i can think of (UPDATED ANSWER). See if that helps.

Comment: I tried your second code and it is bad) UI is laggy and this is bad